# Create prototype scoped Spring bean with annotations?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, scope, javabeans

Is it possible to convert the following [XML configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html) to an annotation based one?

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.package.MyBeanClass" scope="prototype" />
```

I'm using Spring [2.5.6](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/index.html).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the `@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` annotation.

```
@Service
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class CustomerService {
    // ...
}
```

1. [Spring API Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).
2. [Example of the mapping](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/).
3. [Scope annotation reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html).

Comment: There's also a nice constant to use instead of the String: [`BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html#SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)

Comment: In the Scope annotation Javadoc, the constant recomeded is [ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)

Comment: Has BeanDefinition class removed in Spring 4 ?

Comment: @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)

Comment: Or save a little typing with `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`

Comment: Is there any reasoning behind the fact that there is a `@RequestScope` annotation but no `@PrototypeScope`?

Answer (score 7):

As of the current `spring version 4.3.2`, we can use  [@Scope("prototype")](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-scope-resolver) annotation.

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Repository
public class MovieFinderImpl implements MovieFinder {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'd say using a provided constant, as in the accepted answer, is better.

Comment: @herman What makes it better? And is there a JSR standard for this?

Comment: @Steve in case the string changes (not very likely) or you want to search for references using your IDE

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 5, You can use as follows

```
@Component("myBean")
```

`@Scope("prototype")`

```
public class MyBeanClass{//your logics}
```