# Regular Object in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, object, new-operator, boot

How Spring boot application handles the Java Object created with the new operator.

How Spring Boot Container maintains these new created objects and how garbage collections work on these objects

On certain conditions, I need to create objects like

```
Switch(transactionType)
{
      Case SALE:
                return new SaleObject();
                break;
      Case RETURN:
                return new ReturnObject();
                break;
      ....

}
```

These new objects are not singleton, they maintain instance variables.

Comment: Spring doesn't do anything with them, because Spring (generally) does not know about them – impossible to say without sharing more context. The GC handles them like any other object.

Comment: You can always use some lazy initialization and they will become singletons, but I'm reasoning over assumptions because the question is lacking of context. Could you please tell us more of what you want to achieve?

Comment: How is the object created in the Spring Boot application handled? When the Spring boot application starts does it start a heap memory along with spring container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create prototype scoped Spring bean with annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921715/create-prototype-scoped-spring-bean-with-annotations)